# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a normal operator $A$, then $\left.A\right|_{{\mathcal N(\lambda-A)}^\perp}$ is well-defined and normal as well

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, normal-operator

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $A$ be a *normal*$^1$ linear operator on $H$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ be an eigenvalue of $A$.

> Are we able to show that ${\mathcal N(\lambda-A)}^\perp\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$ and $$A_\lambda:=\left.A\right|_{{\mathcal N(\lambda-A)}^\perp}$$ is normal well?

The claim is easily seen to be true when $\mathcal D(A)=H$ and $A$ is bounded.

---

$^1$ i.e. $A$ is densely-defined, $\mathcal D(A)=\mathcal D(A^\ast)$ and $$\left\|Ax\right\|_H=\left\|A^\ast x\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathcal D(A).\tag1$$

Comment: Take a look at the operator on $L^2(\Bbb R)\oplus\Bbb R$ given by $(f,z)\mapsto (x\cdot f, z)$ (with the usual domain of the $x$ operator). This is the operator $A=x\oplus\Bbb1$. It is self-adjoint, hence normal. Its only eigenvalue is $1$, the kernel of $1-A$ is $0\oplus\Bbb R$ (in the above decomposition). The complement of that kernel is $L^2(\Bbb R)\oplus 0$. This is not contained in the domain of $A$!